# RegEx Case-Insensitive Inline

Tags: regex, vb.net, validation, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

I have the following Regular Expression in VB.NET which works just fine.

`(Istr_)*(8[25]\d{5}[0-9xX]{2}|DR\d{5}[0-9xX]{2}|R\d{2}-\d{4})`

However, I want the "Istr_" part only to be case-insensitive, while the rest of the expression remains case-sensitive. I attempted that by simply adding "?i:" according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx) like so:

`(?i:Istr_)*(8[25]\d{5}[0-9xX]{2}|DR\d{5}[0-9xX]{2}|R\d{2}-\d{4})`

But this breaks the `RegularExpressionValidator` in my form.

Does the `*` have something to do with this? I'm not sure is the appropriate character to join the patterns. I want the first pattern to be an optional case-insensitive prefix to the second pattern.

Furthermore, I don't want to allow spaces, which I haven't been able to figure out how to do yet.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the discussion here: [Can you make just part of a regex case-insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632/can-you-make-just-part-of-a-regex-case-insensitive)

Or make a not very beautiful solution, but works:

```
([Ii][Ss][Tt][Rr]_)?(8[25]\d{5}[0-9xX]{2}|DR\d{5}[0-9xX]{2}|R\d{2}-\d{4})
```

I've changed your * to ?. This means:

```
?: the prefix iStR_ is optional
*: the prefix IStr_ is optional but can occur multiple times
```

Comment: What about my `*` is that the right character for what I want to accomplish with the joining? Also, how do I disallow spaces? And I already read that question and didn't like the solution. Thanks.

Comment: As @FiveO stated, `?` means "0 or 1 times", `*` means "0 or more times".  It sounds like `?` is what you want.  And you are kind of stuck since javascript simply does not support changing the match mode inline.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. :)