# Tricky Regular Expression with a Alphanumeric pattern in uppercase

Tags: regex, expression

Okay this might not be tricky at all for some but at the moment really screwing up with my head.

First of all i don't know what engine i am dealing with, but it doesn't seem to identify uppercase.

I have a string for example

```
Circuit Ref

    Service Type

    A End Address

    Z End Address











52GD J32SD41 O2AE EVC001

    Evolve Internet
```

And I am only trying to extract the string "52GD J32SD41 O2AE EVC001". I have already tried quite a few combinations like

1. `[0-9A-Z]{4}\s[0-9A-Z]+\s[0-9A-Z]+\s[0-9A-Z]+`
2. `[A-Z0-9]{4}\s\W+\s\W+\s\W+`
3. `[A-Z0-9]{4}\s[A-Z0-9\s]*[A-Z0-9\s]*[A-Z0-9\s]*`

Nothing seem to work...I want to keep the expression fairly flexible as the expression can change order of the letters and digits. but the pattern is mostly same. Any nudge in a right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the tool being used here? Your first regex works in JavaScript and many other flavors.

Comment: I am actually using it in cisco process orchestrator... which is based on .Net. The first one is coming up with expressions with lowercase as well.. which is NOT what i want.

Comment: Maybe you need to escape backslashes as in `\\s`.  You may also need to escape some meta characters like `\+` vs. `+`.  Possibly even `\[` and `\{`.

Comment: @PinkNinja: Check your options. There should be an option to make the pattern case-sensitive.

Comment: Doh ! *Having a duh moment*... .. Thanks Heaps...I found the switch and it works!

Comment: @PinkNinja: Is it in **Process Editor** > **Tools** > **Regex Matcher** > **Match dialog box**? Or just a **Find** dialog?

Comment: It is a Regex Matcher

Answer (score 0):

This is wild guess, but please try following things:

- in front of the regex add `(?-i)` ([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632/can-you-make-just-part-of-a-regex-case-insensitive),  [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html), [net page about regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx))
- enclose regex with `(?-i: ... )`
- enclose regex with `(?I: ... )`

BTW. Regarding 2nd case that you tried: `[A-Z0-9]{4}\s\W+\s\W+\s\W+`.

Seem that you tried to use `\W` as "upper case word character", but it is not what it means.

`\W` means anything that is not `\w`. That is any non-word character.