# regex not working as a expected when I feed "disp VARIABLE attr stixpaths limit INT"

Tags: regex

Hello everyone I have a regex pattern as follows

```
"disp"i VARIABLE ("attr"i stixpaths)? ("limit"i INT)?
```

and

I test it with

```
disp VARIABLE attr stixpaths limit INT
```

I use to test it online https://regex101.com/

But I get 0 matches though I believe it should match
am I missing anything here?

Comment: What are your expectations? Why do you think it should match? Did you mean to use `disp VARIABLE (attr stixpaths)? (limit INT)?`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jMrt3w/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew expect this pattern match with disp VARIABLE attr stixpaths limit INT
as you see i means case insisnsitive and limit and stixpaths are optional pluse VARIABLE is there so it is an exact match

Comment: So you want to apply case insensitivity to parts of regex? Like `(?i:disp) VARIABLE ((?i:attr) stixpaths)? ((?i:limit) INT)?`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jMrt3w/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew right. Is the above pattern not doing it?

Comment: Please  check [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58818125/3832970).

Comment: The problem is that you did not use proper constructs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I do not following your answer fix my issue a here it is not working 
(i)disp VARIABLE (attr stixpaths)? (limit INT)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65959029/regex-not-working-as-a-expected-when-i-feed-disp-variable-attr-stixpaths-limit?noredirect=1#comment116620879_65959029

Comment: actually that link  works thanks a lot very helpful