# Have sed case sensitive only some part

Tags: regex, sed, case-sensitive

How do we have sed case sensitive only some part in searching by regex e.g.

```
sed -Ee '/^\s*[0-9]+.+\*FOOBAR=.+\bfoo\b.+\bbar/'  F
```

How do we find exact `FOOBAR=` and any letter case `foo` and any letter case `bar`
Thanks much

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you make just part of a regex case-insensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632/can-you-make-just-part-of-a-regex-case-insensitive)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [fF][oO][oO] and [bB][aA][rR].

Comment: What is 5 times longer?  Longer than what?  What do you mean by "On real"?