# What flavor of regular expression does Apache Spark SQL use for "rlike"?

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Python and Spark, spinning up on PySpark under Anaconda on
Windows 10.  I am going through the `rlike` section #7 of [this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-where-filter) on
the Where Filter method of the DataFrame class.  There in nothing in
[the Python
documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.rlike.html#pyspark.sql.Column.rlike)
about the supported regular expressions.  I sometimes find the Java
documentation a bit more informative than the PySpark documentation,
but it didn't seem to be [the
case](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#rlike-java.lang.String-)
here.

The Python documentation linked to above says that "*extended* regex"
is supported.  I consider
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions)
to contain the most generic (vendor/tool/platform-independent) information on this.
However, it does not cover the case-sensitive specifier in section #7
of the [above
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-where-filter).
*Presumably,* this is `(?i)`.

What flavor of regular expression does Apache Spark SQL use for `rlike`?

Comment: [This section](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/sql/index.html#rlike) says the flavor used is that of Java. Currently this question is falling on the "seeking for recommendations" side ([don't ask me why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423690)); if you could just modify it a bit so that it says "*What flavor does Apache Spark SQL use for `rlike`?*" instead of "*Where can I find the documentation for...*" , I would be happy to write an answer.

Comment: A site I can recommend for regexes is https://www.regular-expressions.info/ (I have no connection to them). It usually says which language flavours support a certain feature. For Spark you should check the Java flavour.

Comment: @InSync: Thank you, I've revised the question to ask something technical rather than seeking documentation.

Comment: @Walter Tross: Being new to PySpark, I'm not too familiar with how it is assembled under the hood.  While I know that it has a reliance on Java, I also see a lot of material online about Scala, which can be compiled to run on a JVM.  It would be reasonable to assume that it re-uses the Java `rlike`, or large portions of the functionality, but I don't know for sure that it is identical.

Comment: @Walter Tross: Oops, you're right. The section cited in *InSync's* comment says that it is a Java regular expression. But it still doesn't explain what appears to be the metacharacter `(?i)` for case-insensitivity.

Comment: Instead, case-insensitivity is activated by supplying a class constant `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` to the `Pattern.compile` method for compiling the pattern, according to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp), [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-java-regular-expression-case-insensitive-in-java), and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). I could be wrong, but there seems to be some disparity between Spark's and Java's regular expressions.

Comment: @user2153235 Voting to reopen. `(?i)` is indeed an inline modifier. The official docs (the third link of yours) does mention this at the *Special construct* section.

Comment: @InSync: Sheesh. There it is. Not being a developer (least of all in Java), I'm quite confused in navigating the Java documentation page. It took a while to equate the `Field Detail` section to what I think of as class member constants. But I should have found `(?i)` in a text search. What isn't obvious is the fact that it needs to prefix the regular expression, and that it applies to the rest of the expression without having to enclose the latter in brackets.

Comment: If the question is reopened and you answer it, can you please add that the SQL API documentation details *should* apply when `rlike` is accessed from PySpark (which I assume from web searching is a synonym for the Python API)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this section](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/sql/index.html#rlike) in the official documentation for SQL APIs, the flavor used is that of Java. I'm no expert on Spark (this is precisely the first time I read its docs), but it seems that this documentation applies for all kinds of Spark APIs related to `rlike` and friends.

`(?i)` is an inline modifier, which enable the case-insensitive mode for all expressions following it. Similarly, to turn its effect off, you can use `(?-i)`. `(?i)expression(?-i)` can also be written as `(?i:expression)`. These modifiers can be placed anywhere in the pattern, not just at the start, although it *is* good practice to do so where possible. More information can be found at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58818125).

Comment: Thanks, InSync!  That's a might fine answer that you cite at the end of your answer, as is the RegExBuddy page cited at the opening of that answer.  I'm beginning to appreciate Walter Tross's reference to the site, though it may have been hard to drill down to the right page on inline modifiers without knowing what one is looking for.  The cited Stack Overflow Q&A that you cite is actually more informative than the RegExBuddy page in crucial ways.