# Keep/remove log line entries containing a word that continues over multiple lines, until the next timestamp instance?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

To remove single lines in a log using regular expression, I'll use the following:

1. If I wanted to remove lines not containing the word TMTimeZoneManager, I use:
   `^(?!.*TMTimeZoneManager.*).+$`
2. And if I want to remove a line containing the word TMTimeZoneManager I use:
   `^.*(TMTimeZoneManager).*$`

Log example:

```
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609480+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:data] TZ,init,rules,2
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609589+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:text] <TMTimeZoneManager: 0x155f0fa80 {
          Location 0 —,
    MobileLockdown 0 —,
} = (null)>
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609594+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:data] TZ,reset,reason,init
2023-10-05 07:47:38.610578+1000 0x789      Info        0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:text] Loading time source: ServerState.bundle
2023-10-05 07:47:38.611413+1000 0x8b5      Default     0x284                126    0    locationd: (Network) [com.apple.network:path] nw_path_evaluator_start [XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX <NULL> generic, attribution: developer]
    path: unsatisfied (No network route)
2023-10-05 07:47:38.611680+1000 0x8b5      Activity    0x286                126    0    locationd: (LocationSupport) CL: #Manufacturing service
```

The expected results would be:

Removing all lines that do not contain TMTimeZoneManager would return:

```
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609589+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:text] <TMTimeZoneManager: 0x155f0fa80 {
          Location 0 —,
    MobileLockdown 0 —,
} = (null)>
```

Removing only lines containing the word TMTimeZoneManager would return:

```
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609480+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:data] TZ,init,rules,2
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609594+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:data] TZ,reset,reason,init
2023-10-05 07:47:38.610578+1000 0x789      Info        0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:text] Loading time source: ServerState.bundle
2023-10-05 07:47:38.611413+1000 0x8b5      Default     0x284                126    0    locationd: (Network) [com.apple.network:path] nw_path_evaluator_start [XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX <NULL> generic, attribution: developer]
    path: unsatisfied (No network route)
2023-10-05 07:47:38.611680+1000 0x8b5      Activity    0x286                126    0    locationd: (LocationSupport) CL: #Manufacturing service
```

The issue is that this is okay for lines that are only one line, but if the log entry goes over multiple lines it will obviously remain strict and either remove all lines except line 2 for the first regex. In regex 2, it will remove line 2 and keep everything else.

I'd like to be able to either keep or remove the whole log entry even if it goes over multiple lines using the timestamp as the endpoint, as the date 2023-10-05 will always be an indicator of the start of the next log entry.

It's for use in the apps Drafts and Runestone, so I'm restricted to regular expressions.

Scouring other posts, I have figured out how I can remove lines containing TMTimeZoneManager, even if they go over multiple lines with:
`^.*TMTimeZoneManager.*(?:\n+(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\.*).+)*`

[My issue now] The closest I have gotten to keep only the lines containing the word TMTimeZoneManager is:
`^(?!.*TMTimeZoneManager.*).+(?:\n+(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\.*).+)*`

It manages to highlight everything correctly that doesn't have TMTimeZoneManager in it, even over multiple lines.

Where its failing is that on the lines to keep, it will only do the first line. I have spent much time looking over other posts and have tried many various ways to both re-write it and also to try to combine both.

`/^.*TMTimeZoneManager.*(?:\n+(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\.*).+)*$|^(?!.*TMTimeZoneManager.*).+(?:\n+(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\.*).+)*$`

I am not understanding how I should get it to also do the same (the correct outcome for lines to remove) but for the lines to keep.

How could I modify or better write the regex to achieve this so line 3, 4 and 5 will be included? And if you could explain where I'm going wrong I'd be grateful to learn.

**Update**: I kept persisting and trying more options, I found one with `\b` and I got it working, but if it’s a hack and there is a better way please let me know. I also noticed I’d left seconds in.

The final working version to remove the whole log line entry not containing a particular word (including across multiple lines) is:
`^\b(?!.*TMTimeZoneManager.*).+(?:\n+(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.*|$).+)*\n`

**Update:**
The suggestions given work on most lines, but I have run into an issue where on some entries it doesn't select the whole entry above the appearance of a keyword. I've got it close but not the whole way. I looked over the links provided and have tried variations with look behind, start/finish, and the best I've come up with are the following, but it's not quite there.

`(.*TMTimeZoneManager.*$(?s:(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).)+)`
`.*TMTimeZoneManager.* (?s:(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).)+`
`(?!=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*).*TMTimeZoneManager.*+(?:\n*+(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|$).)*`

I'm limited to using single line regex as the $1/$2 crashes. Ideally it'd be great to have one regex to keep only lines with any instance of the  keyword and one to remove lines not containing the keyword. Within any word appearing between the timestamps.

Trimmed example below where it is cutting off in one of the log events.

````
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609589+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:text] <TMTimeZoneManager: 0x155f0fa80 {
          Location 0 —,
    MobileLockdown 0 —,
} = (null)>
2023-10-05 07:47:38.611413+1000 0x8b5      Default     0x284                126    0    locationd: (Network) [com.apple.network:path] nw_path_evaluator_start [XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX <NULL> generic, attribution: developer]
    path: unsatisfied (No network route)
2023-10-05 07:47:38.611680+1000 0x8b5      Activity    0x286                126    0    locationd: (LocationSupport) CL: #Manufacturing service
2023-10-05 07:47:39.816687+1000 0x128a     Info        0x0                  499    0    networkserviceproxy: (NetworkServiceProxy) [com.apple.networkserviceproxy:Large] Validated configuration <NSPPrivacyProxyConfiguration: 0x*********> {
    authInfo =     {
        accessTokenKnownOrigins =         (
            “challenges.url.com”,
            “hcaptcha.com”,
            “recaptcha.net”
        );
        accessTokenTypes =         (
        );
        accessTokenURL = “https://URL.com”;
        authType = “XXXX_XXXX”;
        authURL = “https://URL.com”;
    };
    bootstrapResolver =     {
        someURL = “https://URL.com”;
    };
    enabled = 1;
    fallbackPathWeights =     (
                {
            proxies =             (
                2,
                0
            );
            weight = 30;
        },
                {
            proxies =             (
                2,
                12
            );
            weight = 0;
        }
    );
    policyTierMap =     (
                {
            policy =             {
                conditions =                 (
                    “XXXX_XXXX”,
                    “XXXX_XXXX_XXXX”
                );
            };
            tier = SUBSCRIBER;
        }
    );
    preferredPathEnabledPercentage = 80;
    proxies =     (
                {
            preferredPathConfigUri = “https://URL.com:443”;
            TMTimeZoneManager = “XXXX_XXXX”;
            proxyKeyInfo =             (
                {length = 91, bytes = 0x******** XXXXXX },
                {length = 91, bytes = 0x******** XXXXXX }
            );
            proxyURL = “https://URL.com:443”;
            supportsFallback = 1;
            tokenKeyInfo = {length = 342, bytes = 0x******** XXXXXX };
            vendor = XXXX;
        },
                {
            TMTimeZoneManager = “XXXX_XXXX”;
            proxyKeyInfo =             (
                {length = 91, bytes = 0x******** XXXXXX }
            );
            proxyURL = “https://URL.com:443”;
            tokenKeyInfo = {length = 342, bytes = 0x******** XXXXXX };
            vendor = “XXXX”;
        }
    );
    version = 1;
}
2023-10-05 07:47:46.212587+1000 0x8b5      Default     0x284                126    0    locationd: (Network) [com.apple.network:path] nw_path_evaluator_start```
````

Comment: By "*Drafts and Runestone*", do you mean [this Drafts](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/drafts/id1236254471) and [this Runestone](https://github.com/simonbs/Runestone)?

Comment: My apologies for lack of clarification with an example of the expected result. I have updated with the expected results for each option.

Comment: Runestone iOS app https://runestone.app/ and Drafts https://getdrafts.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the whole log line entry not containing a particular word (including across multiple lines):

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} (?!.*\bTMTimeZoneManager\b).*(?:\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} |.*\bTMTimeZoneManager\b).*)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}`  Match a date like pattern followed by a space
- `(?!.*\bTMTimeZoneManager\b).*` Assert that the lines does not contain the word TMTimeZoneManager, and if that is true then match the whole line
- `(?:` Non capture group
  `\n` Match a newline

  - `(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} |.*\bTMTimeZoneManager\b)` Negative lookahead to assert that the lines does not start with a dateline pattern and does not contain the word TMTimeZoneManager
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2HJrpF/1)

If you want to remove optional trailing newlines:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} (?!.*\bTMTimeZoneManager\b).*(?:\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} |.*\bTMTimeZoneManager\b).*)*\n?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S7pEsP/1)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, both those solutions work perfectly.

Comment: I ran into a problem with longer entries where it won’t select the whole entry only from the keyword. It seems to only start looking at the keyword. I tried adding in the line start date but couldn’t crack it. Have update the info above but was conscious of it becoming too long.

Comment: @Avibright Can you update or create a regex101 link like this one https://regex101.com/r/2HJrpF/1 and add the data that it should match that is currently doesn't?

Comment: @Avibright Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/RIJZ7M/1

Comment: I’m so sorry @the-fourth-bird my Macs & devices are hacked to hades, they’ve now blocked access to regex101.com on all four browsers (which is why I’m needing to mess with logs). It’s not a huge deal breaker if I can’t get longer entries over many lines to work, I could check it over first and remove them manually and then paste them back. The examples you gave me previously get it most of the way there which saves a lot of time and I’m grateful.

Comment: @Avibright `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} (?!.*\bTMTimeZoneManager\b).*(?:\n(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} |.*\bTMTimeZoneManager\b).*)*(?=\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} |\Z)`

Comment: That works for an exact match and any match removing the \b. You’re my hero, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(The apps you mentioned are iOS apps, which likely means that they are using Swift's regex engine. I don't own any Apple products to test the regex myself, and all regex101 links in this answer uses PCRE2, but I'm 99% sure that it will work the same on the apps.)</sub>

This is one classic use case of [The Best Regex Trick™](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html). You have done a very good job on your own; you are mere millimeters away from the result.

This regex of yours has done most of the work:

```
^.*TMTimeZoneManager.*(?:\n+(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\.*).+)*$
|
^(?!.*TMTimeZoneManager.*).+(?:\n+(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\.*).+)*$
```

Let's simplify it a bit:

1. First alternative:

   ```
    .*TMTimeZoneManager.*
    (?s:(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}).)+
   ```

   `^` is not needed since `.*` will match right after line breaks, as `.` matches anything but not line breaks. `(?s:)` is an [inline modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43632) which allow `.` to also match such character.
2. Second alternative

   ```
    .+(?:\n|\Z)
   ```

   Since the lines with `TMTimeZoneManager` are already consumed by the first alternative, we can cut it loose and match the other lines with `.+`, then either a line break (`\n`) or the end of the entire text (`\Z`). This won't match blank lines, however.

The last step is to add some capturing groups:

```
(.*TMTimeZoneManager.*(?s:(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}).)+)
|
(.+(?:\n|\Z))
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/UKAtdg/1).

If a line or a group of lines contains `TMTimeZoneManager`, it will be stored in group 1. Otherwise, it will be in group 2. These two groups are mutually exclusive, which means you can simply use either `$1` or `$2` to remove one and keep the other.

[Replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/UKAtdg/2):

```
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609589+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:text] <TMTimeZoneManager: 0x155f0fa80 {
          Location 0 —,
    MobileLockdown 0 —,
} = (null)>
```

[Replace with `$2`](https://regex101.com/r/UKAtdg/3):

```
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609480+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:data] TZ,init,rules,2
2023-10-05 07:47:38.609594+1000 0x789      Default     0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:data] TZ,reset,reason,init
2023-10-05 07:47:38.610578+1000 0x789      Info        0x0                  121    0    timed: [com.apple.timed:text] Loading time source: ServerState.bundle
2023-10-05 07:47:38.611413+1000 0x8b5      Default     0x284                126    0    locationd: (Network) [com.apple.network:path] nw_path_evaluator_start [XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX <NULL> generic, attribution: developer]
    path: unsatisfied (No network route)
2023-10-05 07:47:38.611680+1000 0x8b5      Activity    0x286                126    0    locationd: (LocationSupport) CL: #Manufacturing service
```

Comment: Thanks InSync, the sites just says it can use NSRegularExpression, they don’t elaborate more detail on which specific type. The first one works perfectly to remove lines with the keyword: `.*TMTimeZoneManager.*(?s:(?!\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}).)+` I couldn’t get the second one working to remove lines not containing the keyword. I’ll have a read through the first link and see what I can glean, the second link I can’t access unfortunately, it oddly gives an outdated browser error on the latest versions of all those that are installed.

Comment: @Avibright `NSRegularExpression` is [a Swift class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression). The regexes that you need should be found at [these](https://regex101.com/r/UKAtdg/2) [links](https://regex101.com/r/UKAtdg/3). In case the links are unaccessible for whatever reasons, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQXTo.png) is what I see.

Comment: I see from the screenshot this is a resource I’ve used before and had forgotten about, not sure why it’s not working tonight though. Have bookmarked those to learn more from as I’m finding lots of ways to use regex to process data.